# local branches which are clones of remotes start with merge commit?

Tags: git

I have the following remote branch `remotes/origin/develop`. I want to start developing locally on that branch so I do this `$ git checkout -b develop origin/develop`. Is it true that git merges `origin/develop` into `develop` which starts this new `develop` branch with merge commit? So that I look into the log I see the following:

```
$ git log
commit 752d5efd3ee89315098a097a5987c20b18839b6c
Merge: 61b04d2 1d32465
    Merge branch 'develop' of 'origin' into develop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no , this is not true, because before you have made `git checkout -b ......` you didn't have local develop branch, after execution of this command you have got the exact local copy of the remote develop branch. about:

```
$ git log
commit 752d5efd3ee89315098a097a5987c20b18839b6c
Merge: 61b04d2 1d32465
    Merge branch 'develop' of 'origin' into develop
```

this is just a snapshot of history of the develop branch. It was made earlier by someone else.

Comment: thanks, so it just creates a new head of `develop` branch pointing to the last commit of `origin/develop`, right?